# Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I am running a `php:7-fpm-alpine` Docker container and have a Symfony command that calls the following function (simplified a bit for display here):

```
protected function getNextEndpointAsObj()
{
    $asObj = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.muckrock.com/api_v1/jurisdiction/?format=json&page=1'));

    return $asObj;
}
```

... and when I run the command from within my Docker container, I get this error message:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: Name does not resolve

... but when I run a short test.php script ...

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents('https://www.muckrock.com/api_v1/jurisdiction/?format=json&page=1');

?>
```

... from either inside or outside the container, I get correct output from the API I'm testing against.

**What's going on here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run a short test.php inside the container too?

It is not a Symfony or PHP problem. In short container's network cannot resolve the IP address of the domain muckrock.com. Look for DNS settings for your container network. Tell more about your infrastructure. It is Kubernetes or something another?

For raw docker container running you can use something like [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/):

```
docker run -it --dns=8.8.8.8 php:7-fpm-alpine /bin/sh
```

Or for docker-compose something like [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#dns) (or for [version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#dns) as more actual)

```
version: 2
services:
 application:
  dns:
   - 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Good answer. I have used my test.php to test IP access both inside and outside the container. It works just fine. So it seems to be something about the function that I'm calling. I thought maybe I was getting rate-limited, but it looks like the API only has a rate limit of once every second, and I'm waiting 5 seconds between requests. So I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Information about name resolving often indicates that the DNS resolver cant resolves IP address by the domain name.I tried to retrieve information by your link correctly but some slowly. Can you try to use something like Guzzle and try to change the request timeout?

Comment: Thanks. I switched to Guzzle and set `connect_timeout` to `120`, but a `cURL error 6` still shows up as soon as the request is made. It's very strange.

Comment: Closing the loop on this: Adding the `dns: - 8.8.8.8` specification in `docker-compose.yml` appears to have done the trick. (I hadn't initially tried that because some DNS queries had been getting through -- but always the first query, followed by a failure the second time.) Thanks again!